# Copy and paste on new page

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that copies the contents of multiple worksheets in a single workbook into a single word document. I want the content of each worksheet to be on its own page, but right now, my code is just copying and pasting over each other instead of going onto a new page and pasting. I've tried going to the end of the document but it isn't working... Any advice would be helpful.

```
 Sub ToWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Wkbk1 As Workbook
Set Wkbk1 = ActiveWorkbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Range("A1:A2").Copy
Dim wdapp As Object
Dim wddoc As Object
Dim Header As Range
Dim strdocname As String
'file name & folder path
On Error Resume Next
'error number 429
Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    'create new instance of word application
    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
wdapp.Visible = True
'define paths to file
strdocname = "C:\Doc.doc"
If Dir(strdocname) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file" & strdocname & vbCrLf & "was not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Doc.doc", vbExclamation, "The document does not exist "
    Exit Sub
End If

wdapp.Activate
Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents(strdocname)
If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strdocname)

'must activate to be able to paste
wddoc.Activate
wddoc.Range.Paste

Next ws

'Clean up
Set wddoc = Nothing
Set wdapp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `wddoc.Range.Paste` I haven't done any VBA in Word, but it doesn't appear you're giving any instructions about where to paste in the document. What did you try when you said "I've tried going to the end of the document"?

Comment: I used Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext after wddoc.Range.Paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use:

```
wddoc.Range(i).Paste
```

incrementing i by 1 after each image. that pastes them one after another.

or more simply:

```
wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count-1).Paste
```

then could get more complicated and add a page break manually in between each if images are small to ensure a new page for each:

```
wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count-1).InsertBreak Type:=7
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821608.aspx

Comment: I tried wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count-1).InsertBreak Type:=7 but it did not work. When it runs through each worksheet, it still copies and pastes over the previous image except that for the last worksheet, it will create one new page.

Comment: you have to use that page break line as well as the 'wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count-1).Paste' line

Comment: I had to make some modifications to this code so now it looks like this: `wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        wdApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7` and unfortunately i've run into the same problem as before, with new pages not being added. do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

First, I incorrectly assumed the "wddoc.range" property would get wherever the cursor is.  This is not true.  You need to use the code provided by Miss Palmer (and replicated below).

However, there is an additional issue I didn't notice at first.  Your loop is set incorrectly.  You are looping through and continually reopening the word doc.  You need to move these lines:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("A1:A2").Copy
```

so that they are immediately above the 
    wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste

line.  This will cause the loop to be executed properly and only open the word doc once.

Also (again, per Miss Palmer), you want to put this:

```
wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste
wddoc.Range(wddoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)after the line:
```

instead of the ".range.paste" that you originially had.

The other issue with your "Selection" line is that you did not specify the application you wanted to use.  This was using Excel's selection by default as it was being run from Excel.

This code assumes that you have a word document that doesn't have enough pages.  Otherwise you could likely use the code you want, but it's unclear why you would have a blank word document with many pages.  You'd still need to specify the app you want to move to the next page in, so put "wdapp." before the selection line.

http://word.tips.net/T000120_Jumping_to_the_Start_or_End_of_a_Document.html

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It still copies and paste over the previous item, and doesn't create any new pages :/. I have been using a work document with only one page.